# Laravel5.5 でURL直打ちのリクエストパラメーターを取得したい

Tags: php, laravel-5, url-routing

お世話になっております。
リクエストパラメータが取得できず困っております。

設定に不足があるのだと思っております。
アドバイスをいただけましたら幸いです。

## 質問

URLに直打ちしたリクエストパラメーターを取得したい

[http://example.com/hello?id=番号](http://example.com/hello?id=%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7) <= 取得できない
[http://example.com/hello/番号](http://example.com/hello/%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7)　<= 取得できた（※１）

## やったこと

「Laravel入門 」書籍を参考に基本動作を学習しています。

/routes/web.phpファイル

```
Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@index');
// Route::get('hello/{id?}', 'HelloController@index'); //　idが取得できる（※１）
```

/app/Http/Controllers/HelloController.phpファイル

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    //
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    // var_dump($request->id); // <= NULLになってしまう
    // exit();
     if (isset($request->id))
     {
        $param = ['id' => $request->id];
        $items = DB::select('select * from people where id = :id',
           $param);
     } else {
        $items = DB::select('select * from people');
     }
     return view('hello.index', ['items' => $items]);
  }

}
```

## 参考テキスト

「PHPフレームワーク Laravel入門 Page.185 リスト5-7」
ISBN987-4-7980-5258-8

## 動作環境：

OS：Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
WEBサーバー：nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
PHPバージョン：PHP 7.2.9-1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 06:56:13) ( NTS )
Laravelバージョン：
 $ php artisan -V
Laravel Framework 5.5.42

よろしくお願いします。
kaz_dev

## 修正箇所

nginxの設定の記述ミスを修正しました。
修正前）
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
修正後）
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

/etc/nginx/sites-available/defaultファイル

```
# Laravel ver5.5
        location / {
                root /var/www/path/to/public;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        #location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                root /var/www/path/to/public;
                # CORS start
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
                # CORS end
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Comment: Laravel 5.5 なら「動的プロバティーでの入力取得」ができるはずなので、その挙動は妙ですね。nginx--PHP 間のつなぎ込みは何を参考にしましたか？

Comment: emusさん
nginx の設定を見直してみました。
結果、hello?id=番号、hello/番号　どちらでもパラメータが取得できるようになりました。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: こちらの質問はnginxの設定をして自己解決しました。

どのようにしてクローズすればよいのかわかりましたら教えてください。

Comment: @kaz_dev さん、自己解決した場合でも解決方法は「回答」として投稿してください。このサイトの用語としての「クローズ」は他のよくあるQ&Aサイトとは意味が異なるのですが、「承認」が概ね近い意味の操作になります。ご自身で「回答」を投稿して、それを「承認」(ご自身の質問に回答がつくと、横にチェックマークのようなものが見えるはず)して下さい。